# How to fix this auth controller and make it work correctly in Node js (Express)?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nodemailer

I am trying to send a verification email with node mailer and send grid when the user signs up. I've implemented needed functions inside User create function. Also added some parts inside login function to check if user email is verified and only after that let them log in. However, it shows some syntax errors in the auth controller and I can't figure out what is exactly wrong?
Here is the code:

**Auth Controller**

```
module.exports = {
  async CreateUser(req, res) {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
      username: Joi.string()
        .min(4)
        .max(10)
        .required(),
      email: Joi.string()
        .email()
        .required(),
      password: Joi.string()
        .min(5)
        .required(),
    });

    const { error, value } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
    if (error && error.details) {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: error.details })
    }

    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
    });
    if (userEmail) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Email already exist' });
    }

    const userName = await User.findOne({
      username: Helpers.firstUpper(req.body.username)
    });
    if (userName) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Username already exist' });
    }

    return bcrypt.hash(value.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
      }

      const body = {
        username: Helpers.firstUpper(value.username),
        email: Helpers.lowerCase(value.email),
        password: hash,
      };
      User.create(body)
        .then(user => {
          const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
            expiresIn: '5h'
          });
          res.cookie('auth', token);
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token });
            var token = new Token({ _userId: user._id, token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
            token.save(function (err) {
              if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
              var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
              service: 'Sendgrid',
              auth: { user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME, pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD } });
              var mailOptions = {
                 from: 'no-reply@yourwebapplication.com',
                  to: user.email, subject: 'Account Verification Token',
        text: 'Hello,\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/' + req.headers.host + '\/confirmation\/' + token.token +
              transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                res.status(200).send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '.');
              })
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
        });
    });
  },

  async LoginUser(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .json({ message: 'No empty fields allowed' });
    }

    await User.findOne({ username: Helpers.firstUpper(req.body.username) })
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return res
            .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            .json({ message: 'Username not found' });
        }

        return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password).then(result => {
          if (!result) {
            return res
              .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
              .json({ message: 'Password is incorrect' });
          }
          if (!user.isVerified)
          return res
          .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
          .json({ message: 'Email is not verified' });


          const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
            expiresIn: '5h'
          });
          res.cookie('auth', token);
          return res
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .json({ message: 'Login successful', user, token });
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res
          .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
          .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
      });
  }
};
```

VS shows the first syntax error in this line:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                res.status(200).send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '.');
              })
            }) <====== under this ) I don't know what is wrong with it but it shows red line under that )
        })
```

I don't think that ) is the only error in this code. How can I fix this one and other ones if there are others?Here is the model as well:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  password: { type: String },
```

**and token model**

```
const tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: 43200 }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Token', tokenSchema);
```

Whhat shoud be fixed in this code to make the auth functions work as expected?
How can I fix the above mentioned ) syntax error and other ones as well if they are visible by eye?

Answer (score 1):

for the typo, you just forgot to close the mailOptions object curly brace.

also, make sure all the time to send a response to the client only ones so res.send() should be written one time when all callbacks are done, considering error handling for sure.

here is an update for User.creat function where you can see the res.send place is changed:

```
           User.create(body)
            .then(user => {
                const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
                    expiresIn: '5h'
                });
                res.cookie('auth', token);

                var token = new Token({ _userId: user._id, token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
                token.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                        service: 'Sendgrid',
                        auth: { user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME, pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD }
                    });
                    var mailOptions = {
                        from: 'no-reply@yourwebapplication.com',
                        to: user.email, subject: 'Account Verification Token',
                        text: 'Hello,\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/' + req.headers.host + '\/confirmation\/' + token.token
                    }

                    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                        if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                        res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token }); // or you can send another response as you like here
                    })          
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res
                    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can I ask a few questions? What about declaring token variable 2 times? First one was used in JWT block. 2nd one for the nodemailer part. I thought about changing token into emailtoken and model into emailToken instead of the Token in nodemailer part,

Comment: your thinking about the token variable make sense, now there is one "const token" and other "var token", both of variables have the same name so this might be confusing a bit, for that, I suggest making naming more clearer like const jwtToken and var emialToken.

Comment: Also is it ok if I change this: req.headers.host in the URL inside email into localhost:4200? I am asking it because in back-end I use localhost:3000 but in the front localhost:4200.